# Cocoa code- how to print 1024 bytes of a file in one page and next 1024 bytes in the next page after pressing the next button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Cocoa code- As iam a newbie please tell me how to print 1024 bytes of a file in one page and next 1024 bytes in the next page when i press the next button? This is how my code looks as of now:

// To print first 1024 bytes, with previous disabled.

```
fileHandle= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: fileName];
string=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
fileData= [fileHandle readDataOfLength: 1024];
[fileData getBytes: buf length: 1024];
[fileHandle seekToFileOffset: currentOffset];
}
for(i=0; i<=1023;i++)
{
    [string appendFormat: @"%02hhx ", buf[i]];
    //NSLog(@"Hex Values are:%x", string);
    [textview setString: string];


    [prevButton setEnabled: NO];
    [nextButton setEnabled: YES];
}
```

// To display next 1024 bytes after pressing next button.

```
-(IBAction) next: (id) sender
{
buf[i]= 0;
[textview setString:@""];
[prevButton setEnabled: YES];
   currentOffset+= 1023;
  [fileHandle seekToFileOffset: currentOffset];
  fileData= [fileHandle readDataOfLength: 1024];
  [fileData getBytes: buf length:1024];

  for(i=0; i<=1023;i++)
  {
      [string appendFormat:@"%02hhx ", buf[i]];
     //string=  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02hhx ", buf[i]];
      NSLog(@"Next Hex Values are:%x", string);
     [textview setString: string];
    }
}
```

Here the problem iam facing is, after the first 1024 bytes are displayed, when i press next button, the format is getting appended, even after i clear the textview. its displaying from 0th to 2046th bytes.
so please tell me as how to print only from 1025th to 2046th bytes when i press next button.

Comment: Reset `string` to an empty string at the start of the `next` method?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to reset the string?

Comment: What happens if you call `setString` once instead of 1024 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to the `next` method appends the hex output to the instance variable (?) `string`.
You have to start with an empty string in the `next` method. Either call

```
[string setString:@""];
```

at the start of `next`, or replace the instance variable with a *local* variable

```
NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

in the `next` method.

Also, as trojanfoe correctly commented, you should not call

```
[textview setString: string];
```

1024 times inside the for-loop, but call it once after the loop.

Comment: Ah, nice spot.  I didn't even consider `string` would be an instance variable!  Tell him about functions as well, and that `[NSFileHandle readDataOfLength]` won't always read 1024 bytes?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! The code is working now. but when i select a file which is less than 1024 bytes, for ex. 154 bytes, its displaying some junk hex values after 154th byte. So please tell me how to avoid this.

Comment: And because i have reset the string as empty string, now when i press previous button, iam not able to display the first 1024 bytes. so please help me with a solution.

Comment: @user2552735: 1) `[fileData length]` gives the number of bytes actually read. - 2) Re-read the previous 1024 bytes?

Comment: @Martin R: yes i want to re-read the previous 1024 bytes. Please tell me how to do so?

Comment: And how to re-allocate the buf[i]? because when i select a new file which is less than 1024 bytes for ex. 154 bytes, its displaying the previous file's bytes after 154th byte. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: @user2552735: As I said, `[fileData length]` gives the number of bytes actually read, so you *know* how many bytes to convert to hex and display.

Comment: [fileData length] is not working in my code. First time when i run, it displays all the values as 0 in the first page. So please give me a solution for this.

Comment: And when i keep on appending the string, the buffer is getting leaked with memory and its displaying some garbage values. Please tell me as what to do.

Comment: @user2552735: If you don't show your current code I cannot tell you why it is not working.

Comment: fileHandle= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: fileName];
string=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
fileData= [fileHandle readDataOfLength: 1024];
[fileData getBytes: buf length: 1024];
[fileHandle seekToFileOffset: currentOffset];
}
for(i=0; i<=1023;i++)
{
    [string appendFormat: @"%02hhx ", buf[i]];
    //NSLog(@"Hex Values are:%x", string);
    [textview setString: string];


    [prevButton setEnabled: NO];
    [nextButton setEnabled: YES];
}  This is the code which is same as above. But here i have included a for loop as, for(j=0; j<=filesize; j++) after allocation the string.

Comment: But when i open a file which is less than 1024 bytes for ex. 154 bytes, that file's string is getting appended with the previous file's string from 155'th byte. So tell me as how to get rid of this problem.

Comment: @user2552735: Please add the *complete current code* of your `next` and `previous` method *to your question*. I will then have a look at it.

Comment: Hey sorry, as you said, i got the proper output using [fileData length].